# Class creation using eval of dynamically-created string of method def's

Tags: ruby, class, dynamic-class-creation

I have a strange situation where the code:

```
c = Class.new { eval parser }
```

... works in IRB (ruby 1.9.3) but not in code. I've tried it with and without 'class Foo' wrapping my methods. This is frustrating, to say the least. I can copy the string parser's content directly into variable parser in irb, and then create the class using the above line and my methods are all there but when I do it in code, they aren't.

Comment: What is your error in you code ?

Comment: There is no error until I try to instantiate the new class. When I try to use my updated initialize (which passes it a DB handle) that fails.

Comment: Maybe a more complete snippet of code can help

Comment: "
    def initialize( db )
        @data = Hash.new
        @db = db
        @source = \"http://feeds.feedburner.com/FooFeed/\"
    end

    def already?
    end

    def nextcid
    end

    def save_ctables
    end

   def fetch
    end

    def savedata
    end
    "
.
    /home/devel/recc_ruby_mysql/ruby/Content/FetcherBuilder.rb:154:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 from /home/devel/recc_ruby_mysql/ruby/Content/FetcherBuilder.rb:154:in `new'

Comment: The string in parser is (snipped) shown in the previous message although it doesn't come clean in the SO editor.  
`code`
    fetchclass = Class.new { eval parser } 
    inst = fetchclass.new( @db )
    puts inst.instance_variables.to_s
`code`

Comment: Please add that info to your question and delete the comments--it's illegible as comments.

Comment: Sorry about that, @Dave. The parser _is_ a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've solved it.**

The situation was that I was dynamically creating the definitions in order to make an optimized parser, and I was building it using incrementally added strings. As you can imagine, there was a lot of quote-escaping involved, especially with the MySQL queries. When I tested in irb, I forgot that using

```
puts parser
```

... evaluated the string while printing, removing one level of escaping while doing so.

The solution was simple: *eval* my string before class_eval'ing it.

```
fetchclass = Object.const_set(
                characteristics['shortname'],
                Class.new { class_eval( eval parser ) } )
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you nailed it!

Answer (score 2):

```
C = Class.new
C.class_eval(code)
```

...Works for me in Ruby 1.9.2, even when saved in a file. Can you try and see if it works in 1.9.3?

Comment: Same error.
`code`
    fetchclass = Class.new
    fetchclass.class_eval( parser )
    puts fetchclass.instance_methods.to_s ## doesn't show my methods
    inst = fetchclass.new( @db ) # crashes
`code`
Or, should I include the *entire* class def in the string including *class Foo*?

Comment: I am dragging down 1.9.2p290 to install over 1.9.3, since the ruby-debuug19 also appears to choke on 1.9.3. :)

Comment: 1.9.2p290 does not die with the initialize( @db ) but it still doesn't contain the methods and fails when I try to call fetch.

ruby-debug19 doesn't work here either, so I can't dig in.

Comment: I'm going to try using the exact code as you posted tomorrow. I'll edit my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: I've learned that it isn't a matter of the initialize() method. It fails when I use standard initialize() and then a separate initialize_db( @db ) call.